# How to write bytes into array, into specific location vb.net

Tags: vb.net, byte

I'm reading bytes from the file, into a byte array

```
   Dim input As New FileStream("scm_app.bin", FileMode.Open)
   Dim bytes() As Byte
   bytes = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(input.Length))
```

But how to indicate that I want to start reading into an array from the fifth index?

```
 bytes(5) = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(input.Length))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is rather screwy.  If you just want to read `Bytes` from a file then you don't need a `BinaryReader`.  The `FileStream` can read `Bytes` for you.  Normally you wouldn't even need that as you can read a whole file into an array like this:

```
Dim data = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
```

If you want to read into a specific position in an existing array though, you can use the `FileStream` like this:

```
Dim data As Byte() 'The array to write the data to.
Dim startPosition As Integer 'The position in the array at which to start writing the data.
Dim filePath As String

Using fs = IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)
    fs.Read(data, startPosition, CInt(fs.Length))
End Using
```

Comment: Thx for your reply jm, but if i need to take 255 bytes from the huge array and put them into a smaller array which is 261byte length, but those 255 should start from the fifth index, how can i do that?

Comment: You need to make up your mind what question you want answered.  I've answered the question that you asked.  If you actually want the answer to a different question then you should have asked that question.  Unless you have a good reason not to, you should accept this answer based on the question you asked.  If you have a different question, start a new thread and ask that question there.

Comment: In my answer, `data` is the array to write the data from the fil into.  If your array is `bytes` then use `bytes` instead of `data`.  In my answer, `startPosition` is the position to start writing the data.  If you want to start writing the data at index 5 then you set `startPosition` to 5.  Just as you did in your original code, I specified that the entire file should be read but, if you only want to read a specific number of bytes then specify that number instead of the `Length` of the `FileStream`.

Comment: @jm im clearly understand what did you mean in your answer, but i wanted to ask how to deal with 2 arrays when i want to copy the content of 1 to another but in a different index. your answer doesn't fit because i can't do "fs.Read(data, startPosition, CInt(fs.Length))" with an array, i can use it only with IO.FILE. But again it was my fault, ive asked the question so poorly

Comment: i guess i just need to use Buffer.BlockCopy instead